# My Laptop's Power LED and Fan keeps on running even after Shut down (after Liquid spill)

Tags: windows, shutdown, dell-vostro

I am using a Dell Vostro 2520 with Windows 8.1 Home. For the past few days (after a little liquid spill), even after shutting down the laptop, power led and fan keeps running till I press and hold Power button for some time i.e Force Shut down. But my laptop works fine.What should i do now? Is there a way to troubleshoot without taking my laptop to a Dell service center?

Comment: Your computer might not actually be shutting down, but rather entering some sort of sleep mode. You have to look at the shut down options.

Comment: I checked everything. Even Changing the OS to Ubuntu. Still, the problem persists

Comment: Have you set any wake alarms in BIOS?

Comment: Nope! I don't even know what that means.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is a Q & A site and you have not asked a question. Please ask a specific question. IMO, since you know what caused the issue (liquid spill), and you have identified this to be a hardware issue, you should have the laptop dismantled and cleaned before you cause permanent damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take it to a Dell service center

Answer (score 0):

Window's 8 shutdown button is actually a hybrid shutdown that has fast boot enabled.

You need to disable this hybrid shutdown / fast startup here:
[image]

Another solution is to try this command in command prompt to shutdown your computer

`Shutdown /s /t 0`

Source : [Tech Republic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-windows-8-hybrid-shutdown-fast-boot-feature-works/)

Comment: Yup I tried this already. This did not solve my problem.

Comment: There was a liquid spill a few days back i.e before the problem started. Is there a chance that it might be responsible for this?

Comment: @KarthikS Hmm okay, you should probably update your question with these details. Yeah if you spilled some liquid on your machine, then it can cause certain circuits to short.

Comment: But my laptop works fine other than Shutdown.

Comment: When you hit the shutdown button and your computer is still running, are there any keys/buttons you can press to turn it back on besides the power button?

Comment: Nope only the power button works.

Comment: You mentioned that you have changed the OS to Ubuntu as well. Perhaps there is some error in the installation file? For your OS not to fully shut down when you press the shutdown button means it is a software issue. Perhaps something has changed with your BIOS? You should really check that out.

Comment: I wiped the entire HD and performed a clean install of Ubuntu. As it didn't workout, I installed Windows 7 Professional. That too did not work for me. Again I performed a clean install of Windows 8.1 Home. So I'm sure this isn't related to software. I've never changed anything in the BIOS.

Comment: Your BIOS is the first level of software that interacts with your hardware directly. They also have boot options in there, so it's best if you double check. It's very possible to have the same BIOS settings despite switching OS.

Comment: I tried resetting the BIOS now. Still doesn't work. I think this might be related to hardware.

Comment: The thing is - you can hold the power button to turn off your computer fully. Holding your power button interacts with software to turn off the machine. If the power button didn't work properly, then  I would think it's hardware.

Comment: I think i must contact Dell.